# Website on Azure App Insights Waiting on Request

Tags: c#, azure, wcf

The first step our website app takes is to call a sql database and check the users API Key. When under load we have up to 10 second delays before this step is even taken. It looks like the server is waiting on the requests, is there a way we can see what’s happening in this initial 3s (in example below).

[image]

EDIT - Query found in logs screen

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you are already using .NET Application Insights. Do you have them configured to gather info to a log file? Have you looked at the log file?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wasn't sure how to look in the log file. I found one of the requests with the issue by operation_id but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: I think Application Insights can log to either a DB table or a log file. So it depends on how you have it configured.