# WCF Service On IIS Is Queueing Requests

Tags: c#, .net, performance, wcf, iis

Good morning,

I have a WCF service using the following technologies:

```
.Net 4.7.2
Castle Windsor + WcfIntegration Package
IIS 10
Visual Studio 22
```

Originally I asked a question relating to some Azure App Insights anomalies I was seeing that can be found here: [Azure App Insights Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73457358/website-on-azure-app-insights-waiting-on-request?noredirect=1#comment129749388_73457358)

I am now able to replicate the behaviour I was seeing that proves the Wcf Service is queueing the requests. I have a test harness that uses multi threading to send off a specified number of requests at once. If I fire off 100 requests and then an additional 5 from different machines, the 5 won't be returned until the 100 has finished. I believe this is on the connectivity to the service and not anything the service is doing. To prove this I created a blank method with a Sleep 100ms  on it that then returned a blank memory stream. The above behaviour still occurred.

It's my understanding that WCF accepts Concurrent calls by default so I find the behaviour bizarre and hoping someone might have some information on configuration/settings I can try.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, on the machine that you host this WCF service on IIS, what's the actual Windows version? Windows Server 2019?

Comment: Hi Lex, thanks for the reply. I'm able to replicate on my local dev machine (windows 11) but the site is hosted on Server 2019

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.